# Kubernetes - Replicated stateful mySQL database

Tags: mysql, replication

Helloo

This is the scenario:

I have a cluster on gke with apache, mysql and keyrock and i would like to scale it up with horizontal pod autoscaler.

For **mysql** i am using **statefulset** and the code is here:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mysql
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  serviceName: mysql
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mysql
          image: mysql:5.7.21
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: 50Mi 
              cpu: 50m
            limits:
                memory: 500Mi 
                cpu: 400m #65  
          ports:
          - containerPort: 3306
            name: mysql
          volumeMounts:
            - name: mysql-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
              subPath: mysql
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-secret 
                  key: password
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_HOST
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-secret 
                  key: host                  
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: mysql-storage
      spec:
        accessModes:
            - ReadWriteOnce
        storageClassName: standard 
        resources:
            requests:
                storage: 5Gi
```

and **mysql-service** code:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql  #x-app  #
spec:
  ports:
  - name: mysql
    port: 3306
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: mysql  #x-app
```

**Problem:** When hpa scales up mysql database, the **second replica** is **empty** and i don't know how to **synchronize** the 2 replicas!

Does anyone have any idea?
Thank youu!!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is late, but you can find an example that includes copying the data from the primary instance to replicas in the Kubernetes docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-replicated-stateful-application/

This example uses a sidecar with Percona's xtrabackup to copy data from the next instance up the chain if needed. (Actually two sidecars - one an init container that pulls the data from the previous in the chain, and another runtime container to make this instance available to be copied by the next instance to start up.